# How to get the an exit status while using declare to "declare" a variable bash

Tags: bash, variables, exit-code, declare, whiptail

I'm using declare along with whiptail to create a variable. The user input from whiptail is defined as the variable with declare.
I want to use the exit status from whiptail (i.e cancel or esc) but I just get the exit code from the declare statement?

Here is piece of code

```
declare DiagRes[$count]=$(whiptail --inputbox "${Description[$count]}"  8 110 \
                                   --backtitle "OVF Wizard" \
                                   --title "${Label[$count]}" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 )
```

If I hit cancel or esc on the whiptail, echo $? gives me 0 because the declare statement was successful

Is there any way to separate the exit code from the declare statement form the whiptail that follows?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a semi-colon: `declare -a DiagRes; DiagRes[$count] = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use declare? If you just wrote:

```
DiagRes[$count]=$(whiptail                                  \
                  --inputbox "${Description[$count]}" 8 110 \
                  --backtitle "OVF Wizard"                  \
                  --title "${Label[$count]}" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 )
```

it would do the assignment just as well, and you'd get the status return. (Non-associative arrays are created automatically if an element is assigned, so you don't need to `declare -a` them, unless you want them to be local.)

Actually, you can write:

```
DiagRes[count]=$(whiptail                                 \
                 --inputbox "${Description[count]}" 8 110 \
                 --backtitle "OVF Wizard"                 \
                 --title "${Label[count]}" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 )
```

because the subscript of a non-associative array is an arithmetic context.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you rici. Not sure why I was using declare, must have seen it somewhere else. As you probably noticed, I'm new to bash :)